# Arch Linux. Gnome 3.22.2. Two-finger scroll doesn't work

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, scrolling, gnome3

After installing Arch Linux on my ASUS Transformer Book T300 Chi I noticed that two-finger scroll doesn't work. Touchpad works fine, but any multitouch gestures don't work, e.g. double-tap for the right key or triple-tap for the mouse wheel.

I tried installing and configuring synaptics through synaptics.conf, but it didn't help; after that I deleted it (and config files) and tried to work around this problem with libinput, which seems to be the proper way of doing it in Gnome now, but it didn't work either.

xinput sees "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04"; Tweak Tool sees my touchpad, but changing settings doesn't affect the problem; standard Mouse and Touchpad settings don't even see the touchpad (only mouse).

Does anyone know a permanent solution to this problem?